# Disable a Tkinter button when variables are at 0

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning python still so the rest of my code may be flawed but my main problem is I cant disable this button when the Wood and Stone variable are at 0. I've tried using a while statement that runs the *button.config(state=DISABLED)* command when *stone > 0 and wood > 0* but that didn't seem to work.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import tkk

class main:
def __init__(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    self.CraftPickaxe = Button(frame, text = 'Pickaxe', command = self.craftPick)
    self.CraftPickaxe.pack()
    ###RESOURCES###
    self.wood = 1
    self.stone = 1
    self.pickaxe = 0
def craftPick(self):
    self.stone -= 1
    self.wood -= 1
    self.pickaxe += 1
    print(self.stone)
    print(self.wood)
    print(self.pickaxe)
def loop(self):
    while True:
        if self.stone < 0 and self.wood < 0:
            self.CraftPickaxe.config(state=DISABLED)
        elif self.stone > 0 and self.wood > 0:
            self.CraftPickaxe.config(state=NORMAL)



root = Tk()
b = main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

EDIT:
what I think is happening now is that its not constantly checking the variables to see if it goes below zero and therefore not disabling at all. What I'm thinking may need to happen is a check that runs in the *craftPick* function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is that your variable is 0 and not a negative number.

So when you check if your variable is less than 0 it won't disable it because your variable is not smaller than 0, it is exactly 0.

Try with this better

```
while True:
    if self.stone < 1 and self.wood < 1:
        self.CraftPickaxe.config(state=DISABLED)
    elif self.stone > 0 and self.wood > 0:
        self.CraftPickaxe.config(state=NORMAL)
```

Also, you must avoid the loop.

```
def craftPick(self):
    self.stone -= 1
    self.wood -= 1
    self.pickaxe += 1
    if self.stone < 1 and self.wood < 1:
        self.CraftPickaxe.config(state=DISABLED)
    elif self.stone > 0 and self.wood > 0:
        self.CraftPickaxe.config(state=NORMAL)
```

Comment: Yeah that seems like that could of been one of the problems.

although what I think is happening now is that its not constantly checking the variables to see if it goes below zero and therefore not disabling at all

Comment: If it solved your question remember to upvote and select as correct answer :) If not try updating the details so I can further help you with it

Comment: Yes thank you for that, Seems very simple when im thinking about it now. Selected as correct answer :)

Comment: You should change "can avoid" to "must avoid" -- the infinite loop will prevent tkinter from working at all.